# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, image, keras, conv-neural-network, classification

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN8eG.png)I am very new to Keras and am still learning and need help to resolve this error message. I am trying to fit the model. I tried model.fit_generated but it's depreciated. I would deeply appreciate any help to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Colab notebook link
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QpmbDnHivRPn8Ahx-uHxA7tl5ym5Aaf0#scrollTo=MqTMLlXcAWZd

Comment: your colab notebook is locked. Please show at least how you are calling model.fit or whatever.

Comment: you should be able to pass a generator to model.fit just as you would with model.fit_generator . I even think you cold just replace mode.fit_generator with mode.fit and keep all the same parameters

Comment: I want to share the notebook with you can i get your email id? mine is sourabh.somvanshi0@gmail.com

Comment: I tried replacing the model.fit_generator with model.fit but it still gives an error

Comment: #Training the model
history = model.fit(train_generator,epochs=epochs, callbacks=lrr, validation_data= test_generator,batch_size=batch_size)

Comment: the model.fit call looks ok, maybe you are using keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator instead of tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator ?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: You should add some code snippet, minimal and reproducible in your question. Images or external links are not accepted. For your error, it is likely for generator definition. So, please add the code where you have defined and preprocessed your data.